# Evaluate a function call given as a string, which was declared with 'require'

Tags: javascript

I need to use a function that I only have access in quotation marks, hence it is a string.

Let's say, the function is called 'm'. The function is an NPM package. I import it to my project with 'require'.

Assume that the string is given to me by another function. Therefore I don't have a chance to simply remove the quotation marks.

```
const m = require('mithril')
let vnode = "m('p', 'text')" // I need this string as a function
```

I made my search through web and came up with two answers. Using eval() or Function().

Now, `eval` works as I expect. Yet I found many mentions that keep saying `eval()` is evil, slow and should be avoided even if I think it is time to use it. I am trying to build a single page application on github pages - just for your information - maybe `eval()` is okay to use in this case.

And `Function()` acts out weird. When I do `Function("m('p', 'text')")`, it returns this (as a string):

```
function anonymous( ) { m("p", "text" ) }
```

... and when I call it `Function("m('p', 'text')")()`, it returns an error, saying:

```
ReferenceError: m is not defined
```

I tried to `require` the module `mithril` again inside the `Function()` call, yet this time it gives an error saying that `require` is not defined. I assume it is because `Function` comes from a different environment and not from Nodejs.

I simply expect the behaviour of `eval` function, without the fear of getting hacked.

Any ideas?

EDIT (to explain further):

I noticed I was asking the Y in an X/Y problem. Here is the X of my problem.

I am deploying a single page application to github pages using [Mithril JS](https://mithril.js.org/). ([my repo](https://github.com/archetypum/archetypum.github.io))

There I need to render mathematical expressions, where [KaTeX](https://katex.org/) comes in.

KaTeX comes with [a simple API](https://katex.org/docs/api.html), `renderToString()` function returns an HTML element that renders to a nicely rendered mathematical expression.

On the other hand, Mithril JS renders VNodes, a special function to describe HTML tags. Example:

```
<div class="cont">
    <p>
        Text
    </p>
</div>
```

... when converted to vnodes ...

```
m('div', {class:'cont'}, [
    m('p', 'Text')
])
```

Now, in order Mithril to view the HTML output of KaTeX properly, the html tag should be translated to Vnodes. I found a [converter here](http://arthurclemens.github.io/mithril-template-converter/index.html)

I addded the converter's code to my project and imported it as a function. The problem I am facing here, is that the converter perfectly converts HTML structures to VNodes, yet it returns them as a string, in quotation marks...

The solutions I can think of:

- Adding yet another package to my project that allows Mithril to work with JSX syntax, where JS can be written interspersed with HTML tags. This will be my last resort, but I personally dislike JSX syntax since it is just a trade-off.
- Using the `eval()` function, which does what I want perfectly, but the security problems are notorious.

Any ideas other?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more elegant to transform the `eval`-like string into an array of parameters, and then call `m` with those parameters. For example, if the parameters are always strings delimited with `'`s:

```js
// const m = require('mithril')
// for demonstration purposes:
const m = (...args) => console.log('called with ' + args.join(','));

const vnode = "m('p', 'text')"
let match;
const pattern = /'([^']+)'/g;
const args = [];
while (match = pattern.exec(vnode)) {
  args.push(match[1]);
}
m.apply(undefined, args);
```

If the function name can vary as well, then use an object with an `m` key instead of a standalone variable:

```js
// const m = require('mithril')
// for demonstration purposes:
const fns = {
  m: (...args) => console.log('called with ' + args.join(','))
};

const vnode = "m('p', 'text')";
const fnName = vnode.match(/^[^(]+/)[0];
let match;
const pattern = /'([^']+)'/g;
const args = [];
while (match = pattern.exec(vnode)) {
  args.push(match[1]);
}
fns[fnName].apply(undefined, args);
```

Comment: Your answer is useful for certain cases, yet a typical string I am going to deal with will have two arguments, one being a tag name with a class, i.e. `span.katex`, another being a list with many more `m()` functions also including many lists as a second argument and so on. Inside this nested lists of `m()` functions, some of them have the aforementioned lists as their third argument, and their second argument is a JSON describing HTML tag attributes and values.
You can go to the following [flems](https://www.shorturl.at/impxI) to see a typical vnode I need to deal with. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's quite complicated. Parsing out all the nested calls would be *very* tedious (not impossible, but an X/Y problem), is there any chance of fixing the input to send a more manageable format, like JSON, rather than a string to try to `eval`? (Your link seems to be broken, best to post the info in the question itself)

Answer (score 1):

I read your edit post, and can't help but wonder why you have to convert `html` to `vnode`, instead of passing html directly to the rendered `vnode`?

Once a mithril component is mounted, it'll return a DOM node in `oncreate` lifecycle method. So you could write a `mathRenderer` function like this:

```
const renderMath = mathHTML => ({
  oncreate: ({ dom }) => {
    dom.innerHTML = mathHTML;
  },
  view: vnode => m("div", "math expression")
});
```

[Here's a demo with `katex`.](https://codesandbox.io/s/8nqmv83v89)

Comment: Thanks! This is a very helpful answer. I keep studying mithril but quite often get lost in the concepts of an SPA framework. Such as lifecycle methods and their relation with the dom, and the virtual dom and the way the dom is updated on route chage etc... Thanks for pointing out that.

However, I could not see the demo working in codesandbox, could you check it? (I see a blank page in the rendering section)

Comment: @hrkucuk No problems! The codesandbox is working on my end, but to be sure I've deployed the code here https://mithril-katex-example.netlify.com/ from this example repo https://github.com/d4rekanguok/so-mithril-katex-example. Let me know if it still doesn't work!

Comment: now it works quite normal, thanks for the reference again. Currently, I ended up creating a whole set of helper functions in [my own repository](https://github.com/archetypum/archetypum.github.io) to find workarounds of my problems. I am basically solving the problems that have been solved before me, but hey, way to learn more, right?
One last catch: If you add [this stylesheet](https://katex.org/docs/browser.html) to your KaTeX implementation the weird looking square-root notation that spans the webpage and repetition of the numbers will dissappear.

Comment: As a final note: I am a student who has a somewhat average experience in the field. After immediately I got confortable with JS, I started learning React. About a year later I came up with Mithril and since a two months I am learning it. It is just so beautiful. I felt  with Mithril the essential simplicity and robustness one can also find in Archlinux and systems alike.

Comment: @hrkucuk yeah, I really like mithril, it doesn't get the popularity it deserve!

Comment: @hrkucuk Comes to think about it, your solution might have some application whereelse (server side rendering for example). Why don't you come over to https://gitter.im/mithriljs/mithril.js and share with the folks over there? Maybe they'll have something to share with you, or at worst it could make an interesting discussion

Answer (score 0):

Since my problem might have many solutions on different steps, here is how to solve the `ReferenceError: m is not defined` problem.

As is it described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Difference_between_Function_constructor_and_function_declaration), there is a closure issue with the `Function` function. To work around it, one can specify a parameter for `Function`, and pass the `m` variable (which defined only in the local scope) as an argument.

```
const m = require('mithril');
const f = new Function("m", "return m('p', {class:'red'}, 'text')");
f(m);
```

Many thanks to Sami Hult who answered in the original place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54063738/6025059