# Convert a string to a function, gives ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function but it is given as a string (originally it is much more complex and includes many more nested `m()` functions.):

```
"m('p', {class:'red'}, 'text')"
```

The function itself is an NPM package and it is imported via `const m = require('mithril')`. When I try to convert it using,

```
Function("m('p', {class:'red'}, 'text')")
```

... console says `ReferenceError: m is not defined`

As I understand it, when I run a local server with Node.JS, it is a different JS environment, and when I call `Function()`, it comes from a different environment. Therefore it does not recognise previously declared variables.

Now, the original problem is quite complicated and hard to describe. I asked a previous question where I detailed the whole picture of the problem:
[Evaluate a function call given as a string, which was declared with 'require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058166/evaluate-a-function-call-given-as-a-string-which-was-declared-with-require)

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate a function call given as a string, which was declared with 'require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058166/evaluate-a-function-call-given-as-a-string-which-was-declared-with-require)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the function `m` in that code string, you need to pass it as a parameter to the function:

```
const m = require(...);
const f = new Function("m", "m('p', {class:'red'}, 'text')");
f(m);
```

Comment: This is it! Many thanks @samihult ! In my case, I needed to add a `'return ' +` to my `Function()`s body to return  `m` function intact. 
Thanks a lot again!