# Use a string in a function, ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am trying to use a string as part of a function.

```
const import1 = require('./import1');
const import2 = require('./import2');

//on above files there is a method, let's call it method1.

const string = "import1"; // or could be "import2"

//I would like to use above string as code.

//This is what I tried:

const functionToUse = new Function(string + ".method1()");
functionToUse();
```

This is the error I get: "ReferenceError: import1 is not defined"

I checked this answer: [Convert a string to a function, gives ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063611/convert-a-string-to-a-function-gives-referenceerror) and it kind off works but I need to pass in the import1 or 2 as a string.

All help is truly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `new Function`, create a FunctionMap and then access using key

Comment: Issue is, you are trying to create a function like: `new Function('obj.method1()')` and such property does not exists. Quick hack would be using `eval`, but this is not recommended. Instead do `const fnMap = { import1, import2 }; const obj = fnMap[string]; obj.method1();`

Comment: As with pretty much all "how do I turn a string to a variable" questions, the counter to that is "What specific reason you have to avoid using objects?"

Comment: @Rajesh This is really truly amazing, that I did not think of this. Thanks a lot!!! Could you create an answer of this, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

why not using object to access function?

```js
const import1 = { method: function() { alert('method!'); } }; //require('./import1');
const import2 = { method2: function() {alert('method2'); } }; // require('./import2');


// Add link to both objects

window.myImports = { import1, import2 };
const string = "import1";
const functionToUse = getFunction(string + ".method");

function getFunction(path) {
  const parts = path.split('.');
  let obj = window.myImports;
  
  for(let part of parts) {
    obj = obj[part];
  }
  
  return obj;
}

functionToUse();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your import statement. Otherwise there is no problem for function calling .

```js
let string1 = "hello";
var functionCalls = (string)=>{ 
 console.log("string inside function", string);
}
functionCalls(string1);
```

You can check example.